# How to change the icon of ionic app?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have designed job portal app using ionic and angularjs. How to change the icon of ionic app?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this link 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html
and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ionic/ionic_splash_screen.htm

Create different size icon of each device .checkout this link http://blog.ionic.io/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/ for size of icons and put it on resources folder

Comment: thanks. you closed it but didn't upvote it on above of 0 button :)

Comment: i gave the up vote to you but it is not showing because i have less than 15 reputation thats why its not showing publicily

Comment: O.o :) NO Problem.Better luck after some time :)

Comment: i created the different size icon for android and ios and put it in the resources folder but still it showing default cordova icon...: - (

Comment: remove platform android and then reinstall it .

Comment: It will work for sure . Check that image have changed inside platforms\android\res  and check your config.xml that  <platform name="android">
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" /> it is written or not

Comment: not working...still the default cordova icon showing.

Comment: Did you check all the thing which i shared?

Comment: images under platform/android/res contains defaults cordova images..it does not got changed... and config.xml does not contain <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />

Comment: My hack method: Search resources/android for .png's in file browser then manually delete all old icons/splash you see. THEN put new images then build

Comment: still facing issue then i will check on teamviewer

Comment: working fine now.....i have replaced all the icons under platform -> android -> res with the newly created one. Thank you.

Comment: Finally you did it and saved my time for temviewer connection . :0

Comment: Links are defunct.

Comment: @BrunoRanschaert Np. Now tell me what issue you are facing?